# PC doesn't load properly when I upgrade from 2 x 512MB RAM to 2 x 2GB RAM

Tags: memory, upgrade

I recently upgraded my RAM as it was only 2 x 512MB DDR2 2.1V, 800 MHz.

I tried to change it to 2 x 2GB DDR2 1.8V, 800 MHz but the PC would not load properly. I now have one old and one new memory in place totalling 2.5GB RAM.

Why doesn't the PC work when both the 2GB sticks are put in?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the one stick you are currently not using in? If it does not work then, you probably have a bad stick.

You should also check what you computer should take. Download System Information For Windows here and run it:

http://www.gtopala.com/

Check what it says against your memory configuration, and check that in your BIOS' memory settings.

Answer (score 1):

Does the PC POST?

If it does then there is no good reason why it would behave like this; if it doesn't then your RAM or motherboard could be faulty (hopefully the RAM)!